# Destructors on classes returned by functions

Tags: c++, class, g++, destructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo {
    public:
    int a;
    ~Foo() { printf("Goodbye %d\n", a); }
};

Foo newObj() {
    Foo obj;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    Foo bar = newObj();
    bar.a = 5;
    bar = newObj();
}
```

When I compile with `g++` and run it, I get:

```
Goodbye 32765
Goodbye 32765
```

The number printed seems to be random.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the destructor called twice?
2. Why isn't `5` printed the first time?

I'm coming from a C background, hence the `printf`, and I'm having trouble understanding destructors, when they are called and how a class should be returned from a function.

Comment: First, avoid undefined behaviour by initialising `a`.

Comment: `return obj;` causes undefined behaviour since `obj.a` is uninitialized. If you change to `Foo obj{4};` for example then you will see that value, and the destructors of `bar` and `obj` from the second call

Comment: Also you should learn from a book or learning resource. C and C++ are not well suited to figuring out the rules by trial and error

Comment: 1. How many times do you think it should be used?

Comment: This question have more depth than you imagine. That's because there should really be *three* calls to the destructor: One when each call of `newObj` ends and the local `obj` is destructed; And once when the `main` function ends and the `bar` object is destructed. That this doesn't happen can have a few different reasons.

Comment: If we modify the program to print "checkpoints" in the `main` function (as is done [in this example here](https://godbolt.org/z/qJ3cO2)) we can see that the first call to `newObj` (in the definition `Foo bad = newObj();`) doesn't call the destructor of the local object `obj`. The second call to `newObj` causes the destructor to be called, as does the end of `main` when `bar` is destructed. This is probably part of the [*copy elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to eliminate extraneous copying of objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's see what happens in your main function :

```
int main() {
    Foo bar = newObj();
```

Here we just instantiate a `Foo` and initialize it with the return value of `newObj()`. No destructor is called here because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision): to sum up very quickly, instead of copying/moving `obj` into `bar` and then destructing `obj`, `obj` is directly constructed in `bar`'s storage.

```
    bar.a = 5;
```

Nothing to say here. We just change `bar.a`'s value to 5.

```
    bar = newObj();
```

Here `bar` is copy-assigned<sup>1</sup> the returned value of `newObj()`, then the temporary object created by this function call is destructed<sup>2</sup>, this is the first `Goodbye`. At this point `bar.a` is no longer `5` but whatever was in the temporary object's `a`.

```
}
```

End of `main()`, local variables are destructed, including `bar`, this is the second `Goodbye`, which does not print `5` because of previous assignment.

---

<sup>1</sup> No move assignment happens here because of the user-defined destructor, no move assignment operator is implicitly declared.
<sup>2</sup> As mentioned by YSC in the comments, note that this destructor call has undefined behavior, because it is accessing `a` which is uninitialized at this point. The assignment of `bar` with the temporary object, and particularly the assignment of `a` as part of it, also has undefined behavior for the same reasons.

Comment: You should mention also that printing (accessing) uninitialized memory is undefined behaviour. Nice answer though :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! If I understand this correctly, at `Foo bar = newObj();`, the object created inside `newObj()` _is not_ destructed due to copy elision, but at `bar = newObj();`, the object created inside `newObj()` _is_ destructed? If so, why? Also, how can I know when copy elision is used?

Comment: Copy elision was possible (and actually required since C++17) at `Foo bar = newObj();` because it was the initialization of `bar`. To know exactly when copy elision happens I suggest you read [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) on cppreference, it will certainly explain it way better than me.

Answer (score 2):

1) It's simple, there are two `Foo` objects in your code (in `main` and in `newObj`) so two destructor calls. Actually this is the minimum number of destructor calls you would see, the compiler might create an unnamed temporary object for the return value, and if it had done that you would see three destructor calls. The rules on *return value optimization* have changed over the history of C++ so you may or may not see this behaviour.

2) Because the value of `Foo::a` is never 5 when the destructor is called, its never 5 in `newObj`, and though it was 5 in `main`it isn't by the time you get to the end of `main` (which is when the destructor is called).

I'm guessing your misunderstanding is that you think that the assignment statement `bar = newObj();` should call the destructor, but that's not the case. During assignment an object gets overwritten, it doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: Technically there's *three* `Foo` objects: One in the `main` function, and one in *each call* of `newObj`. I'm guessing only two destructors are called is because of copy-elision (in either the copy-construction of `bar` or in the assignment) so in practice there's only two objects created.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I guess the moral is that the compiler will create code that destroys all the objects it creates and provided you define the destructor correctly everything will work. But the number of objects created is not completely predictable.

Comment: May be, it's worth to note that a `struct` is equipped with a default assignment operator when possible (an it is for the exposed sample `struct Foo`). Though, even in C `struct`s are assignable and OP claimed to have C background...

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the main confusions here is object identity.

`bar` is *always* the same object. When you assign a different object to `bar`, you don't destroy the first one - you call `operator=(const& Foo)` (the copy assignment operator). It is one of the [five special member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) that can be auto-generated by the compiler (which it is in this case) and just **overwrites** `bar.a` with whatever is in `newObj().a`. Provide your own `operator=` to see that/when this happens (and to confirm that `a` is indeed `5` before this happens).

`bar`'s destructor is only called once - when `bar` goes out of scope at the end of the function. There is only one other destructor call - for the temporary returned by the second `newObj()`. The first temporary from `newObj()` is elided (the language allows it in this exact case because there is never really a point to creating and immediately destroying it) and initializes `bar` directly with the return value of `newObj()`.